# how to share image on facebook and open image as lightbox

Tags: asp.net, facebook, image, lightbox, share

i want to share image on facebook i have set following code

```
 var obj = {

    method: 'feed',

    link: 'http://cwsv2.lokpunjab.org/PhotoGallery/facebookimage.aspx?imageurl=("ContentPlaceHolder1_DataListUploadedPhotos_ImageUploaded_0").src.toString().replace("LargeThumbs/", "")',
///how to set link so on clicking image it will open as lightbox in facebook
   <br> picture: document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DataListUploadedPhotos_ImageUploaded_0").src.toString().replace("LargeThumbs/", ""),
    name: 'CWS Photo Gallery',

   <br> caption: caption12
    };
```

i want to open image in facebook as facebook builtin lightbox but i dont know how to set
 link in var obj

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way I can think of is actually uploading the image to Facebook.
Then, the user will see it in their timeline, and when they click on it - it will be shown as you want it.